# Horizontal checked line android textview

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox, textview

This might be a simple question but I am not able to find a solution after hours of search.
How to achieve Strikethrough effect on the `TextView` given in the image below. The line length should be same as the text length.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
textview.setText(someString);
```

Make sure your textview width is WRAP_CONTENT.